# Fourth interview with the Co-Founder, don't know what to expect, please help!

Tags: interviewing

So I went through the initial phone screening. After a week after that they called me for the second round interview. During the second interview I went over in detail what was on my resume and how I can contribute that to the company and I also asked many questions about the position I applied for. And then they brought me in for another on-site interview (third). The third interview covered the typical behavioral questions like weaknesses/strengths and teamwork experience. The hiring manager told me that if they decided to hire me, they would contact me by the end of the following week.

However, I did not hear from them the following week but got another email from them saying they're going to set up an interview with the company's Co-Founder (which was unexpected). I thought the whole interview process was three rounds, and that was exactly what the hiring manager told me during the on-site interview.

I'm at a loss right now as to what questions the co-founder is going to ask me because I have told them every bit of details of my experience to them during my third interview. Anyone with experience with third interviews please help me get a better idea of what to expect.

Comment: I joined a startup as employee 2XX and one of the cofounders still interviewed me. The founder/cofounder final interview is absolutely normal and they'll likely ask you culture fit questions. I've had multiple founder/cofounder interviews and they really run the gamut. Best option is to stay calm and be honest. Don't be afraid to repeat information from your previous interviews.

Comment: It's impossible to know, but often it's just a **very short 'check-up'** to make sure founder likes you - that simple.  If that's the case, simply be polite and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 7):

It's not *that* unexpected. Founders like to keep the culture of the company consistent - at least, for as long as possible.

If the team you're working with have signed off on you, then the co-founder is unlikely to particularly care about your qualifications and expertise - well, no. They still care, but they will *probably* just defer to the team's choice, unless you exhibit some extraordinary bad judgement.

Mostly they'll just want to talk to you to find out who they're paying, if you're the type of person they want to see on a daily basis, are you perhaps a disaster but the team don't realise.

So it's mostly going to be cultural/personal fit, rather than anything else. If you don't get the job after this, it was definitely for the best - you would not have fit in, and you weren't dinged because of your skills, but because of fit.

Comment: I feel this is the *likely* situation.

Answer (score 1):

We can't guess what sort of questions this Co-founder will ask to you.

If you were summoned for a fourth round, now with the co-founder, tells us that they are interested in you, and that they seem serious in wanting you to work with them.

The best you can do is to keep calm, be confident in your profile and skills, go to that interview, and answer the questions the best way you can (which you will surely do).

After that what is left is to wait and see how things evolve, but chances are you will land this job (keep you other options open until receiving an offer and signing it, of course).